# DPI aware. WinApi

Tags: winapi

Я хочу чтобы при выбранном в Windows масштабировании > 100 % (dpi > 96) мое приложение растягивалось средствами Windows, НО! я хочу чтобы при этом приложение знало коэффициент масштабирования (/текущий реальный dpi). Можно ли как-то это сделать?

Можно решение только для Windows 10, но желательно для Windows 7+

Comment: Лучше реализуйте полноценною поддержку high dpi, глядеть на замыленное окно в режиме совместимости мало кому понравится.

Comment: Задача приложения масштабировать реалтайм окно с изменяющейся картинкой согласно заданному в Windows масштабированию (dpi). Либо это делать мне самому, вникая во всякие графические api, мудреные, если я хочу аппаратного ускорения масштабирования. Либо просто сказать windows что приложение не dpi aware. В любом случае будет мыло, но в запрашиваемом мной варианте меньше работы. Знать же коэффициент масштабирования мне нужно чтобы менять самому размер курсора в зависимости от масштабирования. Ведь при масштабировании средствами Windows курсор не масштабируется!

Comment: Рисуя картинку самостоятельно можно использовать более качественный алгоритм масштабирования.